# cache vs sstate-cache folder in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I was going through the subfolders present inside build folder of Yocto.

I observe two cache folders:

- cache
- sstate-cache

sstate-cache is used for shared state cache
What is the use of cache folder?

I see the following files in it

```
bb_codeparser.dat  bb_persist_data.sqlite3  bb_unihashes.dat  local_file_checksum_cache.dat  sanity_info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the names suggest, it's the bitbake parser (and friends) cache.